# How could I make messages persistent in my app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, local-storage

I want to make messages sent on my small messaging app persistent. Messages are parsed from the front-end to a Node, Socket io and Express back-end.

A friend advised me to use Enmaps (https://enmap.evie.dev), but as I am using Heroku for hosting this could never work. I was then advised to use Repl.it's database features, but I didn't like their service and it made it hard for me to test locally.

I was told not to use localStorage to store messages because it is "bad practice" (?)

What other methods could I use to store messages and why is using localStorage in this way bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has a pretty easy database with some capacity for free that you can use in your NodeJs server for testing purposes (and for actual applications).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will have a look at MongoDB

Comment: Good luck! I have not touched localStorage that much, but I can understand why it would be a bad practice. It is not supported in all browsers, and some browsers will delete the localStorage upon website termination (Safari on my iPad for instance). There are also potential problems that can occur if the same data that is supposed to be identical to the other devices. For instance if there are network errors or the localStorage is not able to store the data, the localStorage can become different and some messages might never arrive even by refreshing due to the fact that it is all stored local

Comment: A database or simply using fs.writeFile() (which is not recommended for commercial use for storing personal data which messages are) works perfectly. I use fs.writeFile fs.readFile for everything that has to be persistent for the functional prototype I am currently developing using WebSockets, Express, and React. If I were to make this for commercial use, then a database like for example MongoDB is a 100% because it allows easier management and adds another level of security to your data. Sorry for being a woodpecker haha 

Comment: I think I will probably just use fs, I don't want to learn a whole new technology just for storing messages

Comment: Good luck! Just make sure you use a database for the messages if you plan on making it into a commercial product :)